# How to make limitation to marks?

Tags: android

I am doing key in marks in every EditText field. Every marks must not be more than 5 marks. I just do not know how to make the limit where is user key in marks more I will toast the must is more than 5 marks. Below is my layout:
[image]

This is my java code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bContinuous_assess:
                String marks1=marks_1.getText().toString();
                String marks2=marks_2.getText().toString();
                String mark3=marks_3.getText().toString();

                num1=Double.parseDouble(marks_1.getText().toString());
                num2=Double.parseDouble(marks_2.getText().toString());
                num3=Double.parseDouble(marks_3.getText().toString());
                sum=num1+num2+num3;
                marks_total.setText(Double.toString(sum));

                if(marks1.matches("")||marks2.matches("")||mark3.matches("")){
                    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(continuous_assessment.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Submitting marks...");
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    progressDialog.show();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter All Attributes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("eSystem").setMessage("Confirm marks?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    new Marks().execute();

                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No",null).show();
                    break;
                }
        }
```

I believe it is done under onClick. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case R.id.bContinuous_assess:
                String marks1=marks_1.getText().toString();
                String marks2=marks_2.getText().toString();
                String mark3=marks_3.getText().toString();
                if (marks1!=null && marks2!=null &&mark3!=null) {
                num1=Double.parseDouble(marks_1.getText().toString());
                num2=Double.parseDouble(marks_2.getText().toString());
                num3=Double.parseDouble(marks_3.getText().toString());
                if (num1>5 || num2>5 || num3>5) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Marks Upto 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   else{
                sum=num1+num2+num3;
                marks_total.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                 new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("eSystem").setMessage("Confirm marks?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    new Marks().execute();

                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No",null).show();

                }

                }   else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter All Attributes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                break;
```

Comment: Thanks, if the TextView if empty, how to make toast of it?

Comment: Sorry, i mean EditText is empty ,how to make toast of it?

Comment: if(textview.get text().toString()==null) //show toast

Comment: Also for validation of text fields use Saripaar library. It will make things more easier

Comment: Thank you. It helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use TextWatcher for editText, dont need to wait for click event

first set `android:inputType="number"` in xml for editText

or

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

and than

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count){
        String strEnteredVal = edittext.getText().toString();
        if (!strEnteredVal.equals("")) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
            if (num <= 5) {
                edittext.setText("" + num);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter All Attributes!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){

        }
    });
```